# scala: how scala converts foldLeft as currying function

Tags: scala

Could someone explain how currying happens in foldLeft for the below example:

```
val numbers = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
>numbers: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
val numberFunc = numbers.foldLeft(List[Int]())_
>numberFunc: ((List[Int], Int) => List[Int]) => List[Int]
```

My Understanding is:

```
(List[Int], Int) - (accumulator which in this case is empty List, each element of the numbers list)
=> List[Int]     - which is the output numberFunc list.
=> List[Int]     - what does this represent?
```

Thanks.

Comment: This has nothing to do with currying, `foldLeft` is just a higher-order function. Currying is the specific operation of taking *an existing function* with multiple arguments and turning it into a set of nested of functions each with a single argument. Scala has syntax to make it easy to express the resulting curried functions, but that does not mean that any function using that syntax is a curried function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Step by step:

- `foldLeft` on a `List[A]` has a signature `foldLeft[B](b: B)(f: (B, A) => B): B`
- therefore, in general, for a `list: List[A]` and `b: B`, the curried expression `list.foldLeft(b) _` would have type `((B, A) => B) => B`
- `numbers` has type `List[Int]`, thus `A` is inferred to be `Int`
- `List[Int]()` has type `List[Int]`, thus `B` is inferred to be `List[Int]`
- Substituting `Int` for `A` and `List[Int]` for `B` in `((B, A) => B) => B`, you obtain `(List[Int], Int) => List[Int]) => List[Int]`. That's exactly what the compiler gives you.

In words:

```
  (numberFunc :                       // `numberFunc` is a function that
     (                                // given a function that
       (List[Int], Int)               //   takes an accumulator and an int
       =>                             //   and produces 
       List[Int]                      //   an updated list of ints
     )
     =>                               // produces
     List[Int]                        // a list of ints
  )
```